# Can't get SoX to play mp3 stream with query parameters

Tags: python-2.7, sox

I'm trying to use AlexaPi with SoX as the audio processor (since it has effects, which VLC lacks). For the most part it works, however I found that it fails on some Alexa requests because Alexa returns a URL with required query parameters after the URL, and SoX things the whole string after the "." is the file type. Here's an example of the error message generated by AlexaPi's main.py routine:

```
2017-09-15 17:51:50 DEBUG: Error attempting play. sox FAIL formats: no handler for file extension `mp3?Expires=1505541107&Signature=g~nHwqbFYxYYPd3WHHYgDdM2Ukvw0J9OICcBI2Jq9M6ORM7pLp97pwt4I3k-S76f3EUC-543csgXOsbRboqXl8RQqqrp3~xxsegy6E-7Y4Fq2itICT14SsmLxXMTr3WRxzOaCujqhvX7vaUENBgH2Tg47RKRqvQTkx5g44iBokRsEgwcFNdQdEKllzfN1I~srBroUMy97XL1NYUVcOPeuRG0ctmu3jsxgKVlONhanc1AHx8wqqU9dJvGcl3OtyD2vw7lRxE2f6aUavgm0ayKpkmVdJyczsk5yJlIMSawjCMoUkLpQrHaU4EzI0w5YsQLggjQEe5KAlsHlNTKY8eRmg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJMAIYIGWWT37OIHA'
```

Any ideas on how to address this? The expiration, signatures, and key-pair-id are all required in order to fetch the response from Amazon, so I can't simply strip them off.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I figured it out. You just need to specify the file type explicitly before the URL string on the call, i.e., "-t mp3". SoX is ok with the URL, it just couldn't figure out what type of sound file it was, because of the query string that came after .mp3. if you explicitly tell it the type, it goes by what you tell it.

Answer (score 1):

I add `&dummysox.mp3` to end of the URL:

```
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&client=tw-ob&tl=ru&
q=%D0%AF%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB&dummysox.mp3
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30502921)